# AVVideoComposition doesn't add Text to video - iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift3, catextlayer, avvideocomposition

I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198189/swift-3-how-to-export-video-with-text-using-avvideocomposition) regarding exporting a video with a textOverlay (using `AVVideoComposition`). I am trying to apply a `CATextLayer` overlay to a video in swift using the following method :

```
     @IBOutlet weak var subTitle1: UITextField!


    func applyVideoEffectsToComposition(_ composition: AVMutableVideoComposition!, size: CGSize) {

    // 1 - Set up the text layer
      let subTitle1Text =            CATextLayer()
      subTitle1Text.font =           "Helvetica-Bold" as CFTypeRef
      subTitle1Text.frame =          CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: 100)
      subTitle1Text.string =         subTitle1.text
 //     subTitle1Text.string =       "Sheep"       ****No subtitle on output video if replace above line  with this one ****

    subTitle1Text.alignmentMode =  kCAAlignmentCenter
    subTitle1Text.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    // 2 - The usual overlay
    let overlayLayer =   CALayer()
    overlayLayer.addSublayer(subTitle1Text)
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    overlayLayer.masksToBounds = true


    // 3 - set up the parent layer
    let parentLayer =   CALayer()
    let videoLayer =    CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    videoLayer.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)
    composition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
}
```

**Problem**
When I use a `textfield` to assign a `let subTitle1Text : CATextLayer` I get the desired output video with text on it. However if I was to replace the `subTitle1Text.string` property with some static text such as `subTitle1Text.string = "Sheep"` I don't have any text on the subtitle.

When I preview this with `AVPlayer` I can see the expected text on the video but on saving the video with `AVExportSession` no subtitle is added.

So my question is , what is the cause for this unusual behaviour?

Comment: I just met the same problem. Did you get the right solution?